# Can't check out specific branches

Tags: git, repository, branch, git-checkout

I created several branches in my repository based on [Vincent Driessen's model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).

After long time of development, When I use git bash `branch` command, it shows me,

```
$ git branch
  develop
  f7-body-force
  f8-eos
  f9-contact-angle
* f9-junk
  master
```

Branch `f9-junk` was stemmed from `f9-contact-angle`. Now `f9-junk` is done and I want to merge it back to `f9-contact-angle`, but when tried to check out `f9-contact-angle`, git gives this error:

```
$ git checkout f9-contact-angle
  fatal: reference is not a tree: f9-contact-angle
```

Checking out some other branches also produces same error. So, I tried Visual Studio Git. Again an error on checking out `f9-contact-angle`:

```
An error occurred.
Detailed message: The tip of branch 'develop' is null.
There's nothing to checkout.
```

What is the problem?

Comment: What is the output of `git rev-parse f9-contact-angle`?

Comment: A hash: `be7f7eee1032b73019cd870e60d6b8ae661e0f6d`

Comment: Can you checkout the hash directly? Although, if the branch name resolves to a hash then checking out the branch name should work without problems

Comment: No, same error: `fatal: reference is not a tree: be7f7eee1032b73019cd870e60d6b8ae661e0f6d`

Comment: Even `log` command doesn't work for me: `git log f9-contact-angle` gives `fatal: bad object f9-contact-angle`

Comment: Also, I use VS Git besides Git software from git-scm.com.

Comment: It sounds like your repository is corrupted. Not a tree … try `git cat-file -t be7f7eee103` it should print `commit`. What does `git fsck` tell you? fsck will do a integrity check on your repository's object database.

Comment: Wait a sec. pleas.

Comment: `git fsck` lists a lot of errors like `invalid sha1 pointer...`, `invalid reflog entry...`, `broken link...` and `missing commit...`.

Comment: From `git cat-file -t sha1` I get `fatal: git cat-file: could not get object info`.

Comment: I'm afraid your repository got corrupted (deleted files? corrupted files?) Do you have a backup somewhere? The output of fsck is not good.

Comment: Have a remote repo.

Comment: I was always pushing all of the branches to the remote repo., so, is the remote repo. corrupted too?

Comment: No, remote repo should not be affected by corrupted local repo. You cannot push if you have corrupted state.

Comment: Where did you store your local repository? in a dropbox, google drive, onedrive, or similar folder?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Local repo? No, On my laptop HDD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your repository got corrupted (bitrot on your storage drive, accidentally deleted files, …)

`git rev-parse branchname` should tell you which commit a branch points to. In theory you should be able to check out that commit directly and use commands like `git cat-file -t commithash` to get the type of the object ("reference is not a tree").

Running `git fsck` will do an integrity check on your repository's database file. Usually it only prints benign messages such as "dangling blob/tree/commit", but if you get "invalid sha1 pointer" or "missing commit", then your repo is broken. You are likely required to restore from backup (or a remote repository).

Remote repositories should not be affected by a local corrupted database (you will not be able to push).